# video png overlay issue using concat

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

may i ask help to understand why the png logo appears only on the first video of the concat result?

Thanks!

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -y -i list.txt -i ../logo/logo.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$50:min-keyint=$50:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $25 -b:v 4800k -maxrate 9600k -bufsize 19200k -profile:v main -crf 22 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1" -t 370 1080set.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the 2nd and possibly further inputs have video streams with differing properties, so the filtergraph gets reinitialized, and at that point, since you haven't looped the image, there's no image frame left to overlay.

So, loop the image,

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -y -i list.txt -loop 1 -i ../logo/logo.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$50:min-keyint=$50:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $25 -b:v 4800k -maxrate 9600k -bufsize 19200k -profile:v main -crf 22 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1" -t 370 1080set.mp4`

Comment: Thanks Gyan! im interested to find which are that differing properties

Answer (score 0):

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2007-05-09T07:55:25.000000Z
  Duration: 00:01:29.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7490 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x816, 7403 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-05-09T07:55:25.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 94 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-05-09T07:55:29.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler



Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2007-07-17T09:18:37.000000Z
    genre           : Trailer
    artist          : Fox
    title           : The Simpsons Movie
    date            : 2007
  Duration: 00:02:17.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8591 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x800, 8486 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-07-17T09:18:37.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 107 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2007-07-17T09:18:45.000000Z
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
    Stream #0:2: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 101x150 [SAR 72:72 DAR 101:150], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
```